# Find exact text inside Listview subitems?

Tags: .net, vb.net, listview

In my application I want to add a item of 3 subitems in a listview

first subitem is  : the index number of the item

second subitem is : A description for the item

last subitem is   : A directory path

Example:
[image]

Just before adding a new item I try to search if the listview already contains the third subitem (the directory path) with a function I've made:

```
' Find ListView Text
Private Function Find_ListView_Text(ByVal ListView As ListView, ByVal Text As String) As Boolean
    Try : Return Convert.ToBoolean(ListView.FindItemWithText(Text)) : Catch : Return True : End Try
End Function
```

...Now, the problem is for example if I first add in the listview a Item wich contains the directory **"C:\electro"** as the third subitem like seen in the image, then later I can't add a new item with a **"C:\"** directory because my function is not searching for a full text, my function founds "C:\Electro" when I search for "C:\", it searchs for a piece of text and I need the otherwise.

Then I need to improve the function to search inside a listview for a full text, not for a piece of text.

Last example:

If I have an item in the listview with the string "C:\Electro" and I search if exist "C:\" in the listviews items, the desired result is "FALSE" (Not exists the directory C:\, is C:\Electro)

> UPDATE:

A code example extracted from the class, if you want to see what I mean...

```
Private Sub TextBoxes_Sendto_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
Handles TextBox_Sendto_Directory.TextChanged, _
        TextBox_Sendto_Description.TextChanged

    If TextBox_Sendto_Description.TextLength <> 0 _
    AndAlso TextBox_Sendto_Directory.TextLength <> 0 Then

        If Not Find_ListView_Text(ListView_Sendto, TextBox_Sendto_Directory.Text) Then
            Label_Sendto_Status.Text = "Directory ready to add"
            Label_Sendto_Status.ForeColor = Color.YellowGreen
            Button_Sendto_Add.Enabled = True
        Else
            Label_Sendto_Status.Text = "Directory already added"
            Label_Sendto_Status.ForeColor = Color.Red
            Button_Sendto_Add.Enabled = False
        End If

    Else
        Button_Sendto_Add.Enabled = False
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Button_Sendto_Add_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_Sendto_Add.Click

    Dim item = ListView_Sendto.AddItem(ListView_Sendto.Items.Count + 1)
    item.SubItems.Add(TextBox_Sendto_Description.Text)
    item.SubItems.Add(TextBox_Sendto_Directory.Text)

End Sub

' Find ListView Text
Private Function Find_ListView_Text(ByVal ListView As ListView, ByVal Text As String) As Boolean
    Try : Return Convert.ToBoolean(ListView.FindItemWithText(Text)) : Catch : Return True : End Try
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple little function that takes the ListViewItemcollection, the zero-based column index and a search string and returns whether the search string exists in any subitem in that column:

```
Private Function FindItem(ItemList As ListView.ListViewItemCollection, ColumnIndex As Integer, SearchString As String) As Boolean
    For Each Item As ListViewItem In ItemList
        If Item.SubItems(ColumnIndex).Text = SearchString Then
            Return True
        End If
    Next
    Return False
End Function
```

You would call it like this:

```
If Not FindItem(ListView_Sendto, 2, TextBox_Sendto_Directory.Text) Then
```

The comparison is case insensitive.  If you want case sensitivity you could use the CompareTo method instead of equality.

If necessary you could add error trapping in case the column index is out of range.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a proper answer but one trick you can try :

just add one more column(hidden) 

and write in that `"^" + Directory Path + "^"` and then search for `^C:\^` , it will only find `C:\` not `C:\Electro`

Answer (score 0):

Finally... I did the snippet:

```
#Region " [ListView] Find ListView Text "

    ' [ListView] Find ListView Text Function
    '
    ' // By Elektro H@cker
    '
    ' Examples :
    ' MsgBox(Find_ListView_Text(ListView1, "Test"))
    ' MsgBox(Find_ListView_Text(ListView1, "Test", 2, True, True))
    ' If Find_ListView_Text(ListView1, "Test") Then...

    Private Function Find_ListView_Text(ByVal ListView As ListView, _
                                        ByVal SearchString As String, _
                                        Optional ByVal ColumnIndex As Int32 = Nothing, _
                                        Optional ByVal MatchFullText As Boolean = True, _
                                        Optional ByVal IgnoreCase As Boolean = True) As Boolean

        Dim ListViewColumnIndex As Int32 = ListView.Columns.Count - 1

        Select Case ColumnIndex

            Case Is < 0, Is > ListViewColumnIndex ' ColumnIndex is out of range

                Throw New Exception("ColumnIndex is out of range. " & vbNewLine & _
                                    "ColumnIndex Argument: " & ColumnIndex & vbNewLine & _
                                    "ColumnIndex ListView: " & ListViewColumnIndex)

            Case Nothing ' ColumnIndex is nothing

                If MatchFullText AndAlso IgnoreCase Then ' Match full text, All columns, IgnoreCase
                    For Each Item As ListViewItem In ListView.Items
                        For X As Int32 = 0 To ListViewColumnIndex
                            If Item.SubItems(X).Text.ToLower = SearchString.ToLower Then Return True
                        Next
                    Next
                ElseIf MatchFullText AndAlso Not IgnoreCase Then ' Match full text, All columns, CaseSensitive
                    For Each Item As ListViewItem In ListView.Items
                        For X As Int32 = 0 To ListViewColumnIndex
                            If Item.SubItems(X).Text = SearchString Then Return True
                        Next
                    Next
                ElseIf Not MatchFullText AndAlso IgnoreCase Then ' Match part of text, All columns, IgnoreCase
                    If ListView1.FindItemWithText(SearchString) IsNot Nothing Then _
                         Return True _
                    Else Return False
                ElseIf Not MatchFullText AndAlso Not IgnoreCase Then ' Match part of text, All columns, CaseSensitive
                    For Each Item As ListViewItem In ListView.Items
                        For X As Int32 = 0 To ListViewColumnIndex
                            If Item.SubItems(X).Text.Contains(SearchString) Then Return True
                        Next
                    Next
                End If

            Case Else ' ColumnIndex is other else

                If MatchFullText AndAlso IgnoreCase Then ' Match full text, ColumnIndex, IgnoreCase
                    For Each Item As ListViewItem In ListView.Items
                        If Item.SubItems(ColumnIndex).Text.ToLower = SearchString.ToLower Then Return True
                    Next
                ElseIf MatchFullText AndAlso Not IgnoreCase Then  ' Match full text, ColumnIndex, CaseSensitive
                    For Each Item As ListViewItem In ListView.Items
                        If Item.SubItems(ColumnIndex).Text = SearchString Then Return True
                    Next
                ElseIf Not MatchFullText AndAlso IgnoreCase Then ' Match part of text, ColumnIndex, IgnoreCase
                    For Each Item As ListViewItem In ListView.Items
                        If Item.SubItems(ColumnIndex).Text.ToLower.Contains(SearchString.ToLower) Then Return True
                    Next
                ElseIf Not MatchFullText AndAlso Not IgnoreCase Then ' Match part of text, ColumnIndex, CaseSensitive
                    For Each Item As ListViewItem In ListView.Items
                        If Item.SubItems(ColumnIndex).Text.Contains(SearchString) Then Return True
                    Next
                End If

        End Select

        Return False

    End Function

#End Region
```